# Is the following usage of "multitude" correct?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, is the usage of multitude correct?

> A major challenge is the vast multitude of possible adversaries.

The sentence sounds a little "off" (for lack of a better word), but I am unable to pinpoint what the problem is.

I would appreciate it if I could know if the sentence is fine, or if any changes are needed.

Comment: It maybe could be worded better, but it's correct.

Comment: A *multitude* generally applies to a large "homogeneous" group. In OP's context the possible adversaries probably *don't* manifest as a cohesive set all in one place at the same time (a "horde"). What matters is the fact that there are *lots of them* (and perhaps the implication that they are of *many different types*), so I think ***multiplicity*** would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the the word multitude makes sense in this context, being defined as:

> [multitude](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/multitude) (noun) A large number of people or things.

However, in this sentence I think that the use of "**vast**" is a tautology, and you should use one or the other; rather, one or the other will suffice.

Source: [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/)

Comment: Ah! I think I realized, now, what felt "off" - the usage of "vast multitude". Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently "vast multitude" was more popular in the past: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vast+multitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvast%20multitude%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks: Whoa! Did not know about Google Ngram Viewer. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Please credit Oxford Dictionaries *online* as the source of your direct quotation.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the problem with the answer?

Comment: What I would think is that the ***real*** problem with the sentence is that a *multitude* is not the same thing as a *variety*. If there were 10,000,000 orcs, all exactly alike, that would indeed be a vast multitude. But if one of them can be dealt with, any of them can be dealt with. You really should say *"A major challenge is the vast variety of possible adversaries."*

Comment: Peter Shor makes a compelling argument for the more *nuanced* "variety, but "multitude" will work. My down-vote was meant to encourage you to cite your sources -  which are required for direct quotations - an amendment, I see you've made. Down-vote rescinded, and +1. Thank you, Robert.

Comment: @PeterShor It's true that, if every orc is identical to every other, then the same technique can be used to defeat any one of them, however if there are 10 million of them it might not be possible to apply the technique 10 million times. The technique for dealing with cockroaches is pretty consistent but getting rid of all the little blighters is still quite difficult.